# ASUS K52JR: Is it possible to recover bios update failure without resoldering the bios chip?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios

Just bricked an ASUS K52JR (bought around 2010) after using the notorious EasyFlash. The laptop **won't even power up**. I've checked tons of posts, and basically found two contradicting solutions:

1. Easy, no need to resolder the chip (looks like a msop packaging), simply reset the cmos, and the machine will be able to power up again. Then it is possible to restore the bios rom using a usb disk.
2. Bad luck, boot block is probably gone. get a new chip from ebay and resolder it.

I think it is probably the second case. But then I think if the board has a dual bios, might there be a chance to recover it without resoldering the chip?

---

Edit: I opened the laptop, and removed cmos battery for long enough. The laptop still won't power up.

So now comes to the question if replacing that little bios chip would solve all the problem? I think I can do it without using hot air gun...

---

Edit: I finally solved the problem by replacing the bios chip on the motherboard. The chip I bought from Chip24 on ebay.it. Immediately after I plugged in AC, the motherboard powered up again, showing a bios version of 213 (I was having a 206 before the update failure).

Lesson learned: ASUS sucks. They create tons of trouble for you to replace BIOS. And they intentionally provided a crappy bios updater. For those who didn't know how to replace the BIOS chip, ASUS will easily charge you 200-300 Euros for a new motherboard.

Comment: First step;  Confirm if it has a dual bios.

Comment: @Ramhound I was looking for a screw driver...gonna do it tomorrow morning.

Comment: First do a hard reset, unplug power, remove battery, hold power button down for a minute, connect ac only, power up and see if it recovers. If this does not work try it again, this time also remove the cmos battery for 15 min,  If you get it working do not forget to enter bios immediately and set date and time before the os loads. Do you remember what bios vendor it had, Phoenix?

Comment: Some bios crisis recovery methods at this link, they are bios vendor specific...https://www.bios-mods.com/bios-recovery/phoenix-bios-recovery/

Comment: @Moab No luck. I cannot locate a second bios chip. And there is no jumper on the whole damn board.

Comment: It does not sound like the motherboard has a dual-bios functionality, most don't, only motherboards that exceed the mid-range price point normally do.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you think replacing bios chip would solve all the problem?

Comment: If you feel you have the technical skills to do it and have a source for the part.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. It seems the only way. I know how to disassemble it into pieces (from youtube), and I just ordered a chip on ebay. And msop does not seem to be that difficult...

Comment: @TroyWoo long shot, but do you still know which chip you replaced? I have the same problem, but I see multiple chips on the motherboard that could be it.